# Spring Boot Maven Plugin keeps duplicate jars -- is there a fix?

Tags: maven, jar, spring-boot

We are seeing very large jar files created by Spring Boot Maven Plugin and upon examining them we found that there are many duplicate jars inside of it due to the structure of our multi-module project. We were able to reduce the size by excluding jars in the plugin config section, but this is a tedious and error-prone approach.

We did not find any options to de-dupe the output jar, but maybe we missed something. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the plugin. Can you share the necessary configuration to reproduce the problem?

Comment: It sounds to me like maybe you are combining multiple executable jars into a single one. That doesn't really make much sense - it's better to combine lilbraries, not executables.

Comment: To replicate, I added the following dependency to spring-boot-sample-tomcat pom:
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-sample-ws</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>

Ii think the problem maybe that our common project inherits the spring-boot-maven plugin from the parent, but, still it would be nice if it was smart enough de-dupe. Thanks all for your answers.

Comment: Spring Boot Maven plugin generates that executable JAR, and uses that new artifact as the main one (without any classifier). But it does rename the "normal" JAR as '.jar.original'. So maybe it can be possible in your build to install these _.original_ artifacts (with a special execution of the _install plugin_), so that these ones can really be used as dependencies. But as Dave says, maybe you should work on decoupling libraries from executables.

Comment: Will see if we can separate libs form executables -- seems like the right answer.